# how to get the update manager window visible?

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher

I can see from the launcher that the Update Manager is running - it has the little triangle by it. However, I am having trouble seeing the window. If I click on it from one desktop, it switches to another, so I assume that the Update Manager has its window on that other desktop, but it still doesn't show anything.

If I click alt-tab to switch between apps, I can see that the Update Manager is there, but selecting it just shows me a blank screen. Also, when I select it, while still holding the alt-key, I see the top menu bar switch to 'Update Manager', but when I release alt, it changes back to Ubuntu Desktop.

It's almost like the app is off the screen somewhere, perhaps with just a single pixel showing or something like that.

disclaimer: One thing that might be affecting things is that I have 'focus follows mouse' configured, which makes things a bit funky with the menu not being on the window, where it should be (perhaps there's a way to put it back with the window?) - I like to be able to type into background windows, and manually control which window is in the foreground.

Comment: Try switching the workspace through workspace switcher in Launcher panel , or use Ctrl+Alt+Arrow keys.

Comment: I do that all the time, but the Update Manager isn't on any desktop.

Comment: i would suggest reinstalling it through **sudo apt-get install update-manager** , reboot and see if it helps.

Comment: This is still bugging me in Ubuntu 14.

Comment: This looks like [bug #989588](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/989588).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am having the same issue with not being able to open / view the window using the Update Manager icon in the right side launcher.

**Workaround:** right-click the icon and **Quit** Update Manager from the quick list, then go to the top right Settings (gear) menu and click on **Updates Available...**

This would show the Update manager window.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Odd bug, never happened before, and I didn't just upgrade anything.

Comment: Maybe related: Once I do this and have the updater window on screen I'm unable to resize it using the mouse at the window borders. Does anyone else experience this? It might be a hint in debugging the issue.

Answer (score -1):

**Workaround:** right-click the Update Manager icon on the quick list and select **Quit** (as noted earlier), and then use middle button on the same Update Manager icon.

Comment: In case the icon disappears or you don't have a middle button, you can start _Software Updater_ from the launcher.